# ruby require './blahblah.rb' vs require File.expand_path('../blahblah', __FILE__)

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between

```
require 'blahblahlblah.rb'
```

vs

```
require './blahblah.rb'
```

vs

```
require File.expand_path('../blahblah', __FILE__)
```

I see both of them being used. Wondering what's better, and under what circumstance is one better than the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `require blaba.rb` is searching to your *default gem path* to load the file, which depends on the ruby version you are using. For example RVM will search in `$HOME/.rvm/rubies/...` while a system wide ruby will search in the distribution's default path. Note that this is where gems are located, but you could manually add a library say `mylibrary.rb` in the same path and use it in any of your programs. However, that's an awful thing to do, it's a much cleaner procedure to create gems and install them in your system.
- `require ./blabla.rb` loads a file that is sitting in your *working directory*. You could add the full path like `require /home/username/library/myproject/models/sample.rb`. It will work just about the same. In the UNIX-like world the `./` sign means *current directory*. This solution is often used in `irb` to load say a rails Model i.e. `users.rb` into `irb` or `pry` and work with it.  To give you an example in a shell environment (if you are familiar with UNIX shells, you'll figure it out):

  ```
  GreyJewel ~ » ls myports.txt                                                                                                                                                         
  myports.txt

  GreyJewel ~ » ls ./myports.txt                                                                                                                                                       
  ./myports.txt
  ```
- The third solution `require File.expand_path('../sample.rb', __FILE__)` is used in programs, because it explicitly creates a **full path** using as an anchor the directory which the file holding the line sits, which is a much more secure approach compared to `require ./sample.rb`. Note that when you load a ruby file, you can omit the file extension `.rb`.

Hope this clarifies a bit the situation.

Comment: Thanks. Why is third solution much more secure than second?

Comment: Because that method returns the 'full path' to a specific file which is always safes on a UNIX environment compared to a 'relative path'. Try both on 'irb', you'll get how they work.